# Implementing NSCopying

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, nscopying

I've read the `NSCopying` docs but I am still very unsure about how to implement what is required.

My class `Vendor`:

```
@interface Vendor : NSObject 
{
    NSString        *vendorID;
    NSMutableArray  *availableCars;
    BOOL            atAirport;
}

@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString *vendorID;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSMutableArray *availableCars;
@property (nonatomic, assign) BOOL atAirport;

- (id)initFromVehVendorAvailsDictionary:(NSDictionary *)vehVendorAvails;

@end
```

The `Vendor` class has an array of objects called `Car`.

My `Car` object:

```
@interface Car : NSObject 
{
    BOOL            isAvailable;
    NSString        *transmissionType;
    NSMutableArray  *vehicleCharges; 
    NSMutableArray  *fees; 
}

@property (nonatomic, assign) BOOL isAvailable;
@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString *transmissionType;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSMutableArray *vehicleCharges;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSMutableArray *fees;

- (id) initFromVehicleDictionary:(NSDictionary *)vehicleDictionary;

@end
```

So, `Vendor` holds an array of `Car` objects. `Car` holds 2 arrays of other custom objects.

Both `Vendor` and `Car` are init from a dictionary. I'll add one of these methods, they may or may not be relevant.

```
-(id)initFromVehVendorAvailsDictionary:(NSDictionary *)vehVendorAvails {

    self.vendorCode      = [[vehVendorAvails objectForKey:@"Vendor"] 
                           objectForKey:@"@Code"];

    self.vendorName      = [[vehVendorAvails objectForKey:@"Vendor"] 
                           objectForKey:@"@CompanyShortName"];

    self.vendorDivision  = [[vehVendorAvails objectForKey:@"Vendor"]   
                           objectForKey:@"@Division"];

    self.locationCode    = [[[vehVendorAvails objectForKey:@"Info"] 
                           objectForKey:@"LocationDetails"] 
                           objectForKey:@"@Code"];

    self.atAirport       = [[[[vehVendorAvails objectForKey:@"Info"] 
                           objectForKey:@"LocationDetails"] 
                           objectForKey:@"@AtAirport"] boolValue];

    self.venLocationName = [[[vehVendorAvails objectForKey:@"Info"] 
                           objectForKey:@"LocationDetails"] 
                           objectForKey:@"@Name"];

    self.venAddress      = [[[[vehVendorAvails objectForKey:@"Info"] 
                           objectForKey:@"LocationDetails"] 
                           objectForKey:@"Address"] 
                           objectForKey:@"AddressLine"];

    self.venCountryCode  = [[[[[vehVendorAvails objectForKey:@"Info"]  
                           objectForKey:@"LocationDetails"] 
                           objectForKey:@"Address"] 
                           objectForKey:@"CountryName"]
                           objectForKey:@"@Code"];

    self.venPhone        = [[[[vehVendorAvails objectForKey:@"Info"]  
                           objectForKey:@"LocationDetails"]        
                           objectForKey:@"Telephone"] 
                           objectForKey:@"@PhoneNumber"];

    availableCars        = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    NSMutableArray *cars = (NSMutableArray *)[vehVendorAvails objectForKey:@"VehAvails"];

    for (int i = 0; i < [cars count]; i++) {

        Car *car = [[Car alloc] initFromVehicleDictionary:[cars objectAtIndex:i]];
        [availableCars addObject:car];
        [car release];
    }

    self.venLogo = [[[vehVendorAvails objectForKey:@"Info"] 
                   objectForKey:@"TPA_Extensions"] 
                   objectForKey:@"VendorPictureURL"];

    return self;
}
```

So to summarize the scary problem.

I need to copy an array of `Vendor` objects. I believe I need to implement the `NSCopying` protocol on `Vendor`, which may mean I need to implement it also on `Car` since `Vendor` holds an array of `Car`s. That means I also need to implement it on the classes that are held in the 2 arrays belonging to the `Car` object.

I'd really appreciate it if I could get some guidance on implementing `NSCopying` protocol on `Vendor`, I can't find any tutorials on this anywhere.

Comment: Have you read the documentation of NSCopying? I found it quite clear when needed.

Comment: Yes, read and it re-read it. I rarely find apple docs easy to learn from, though they are great for finding methods etc while programming. Thanks -Code

Answer (score 187, accepted):

To implement [NSCopying](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Protocols/NSCopying_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html), your object must respond to the `-copyWithZone:` selector. Here’s how you declare that you conform to it:

```
@interface MyObject : NSObject <NSCopying> {
```

Then, in your object’s implementation (your `.m` file):

```
- (id)copyWithZone:(NSZone *)zone
{
    // Copying code here.
}
```

What should your code do? First, create a new instance of the object—you can call `[[[self class] alloc] init]` to get an initialized obejct of the current class, which works well for subclassing. Then, for any instance variables that are a subclass of `NSObject` that supports copying, you can call `[thatObject copyWithZone:zone]` for the new object. For primitive types (`int`, `char`, `BOOL` and friends) just set the variables to be equal. So, for your object Vendor, it’d look like this:

```
- (id)copyWithZone:(NSZone *)zone
{
    id copy = [[[self class] alloc] init];

    if (copy) {
        // Copy NSObject subclasses
        [copy setVendorID:[[self.vendorID copyWithZone:zone] autorelease]];
        [copy setAvailableCars:[[self.availableCars copyWithZone:zone] autorelease]];

        // Set primitives
        [copy setAtAirport:self.atAirport];
    }

    return copy;
}
```

Comment: Hi Jeff, Is it really as simple as that? Also do I need to apply the same things to the Car class and all custom objects that it contains arrays of? Basically step down the whole way. Or would it only need to be applied to Vendor? Many Thanks,

Comment: @Code: `copy` is typically implemented as a shallow copy like Jeff showed. It's unusual — though not inconceivable — that you'd want a full-on deep copy (where everything all the way down is copied). Deep copies are a lot more trouble, too, so you generally want to be sure that's really what you want.

Comment: @Code: You’ll want to implement this for anything you plan on copying with `-copy` or `-copyWithZone:`. Note that as @Chuck says, this will be a “shallow copy,” so the arrays may point to the same objects in the original and the copy. If those objects change, you may need to copy them as well.

Comment: There is a problem in your code where you copy your subclasses, as `copyWithZone:` returns a object with reference count of 1 and no autorelease this will cause a leak. You need to add at least an autorelease.

Comment: Do you mean instance variables instead of subclasses? You’re right about those, I’ll edit the answer.

Comment: Shouldn't `[[self class] alloc]` use `allocWithZone` instead? Sorry for bringing this up.

Comment: @jweyrich You’re probably correct, but in typical use this won’t matter much.

Comment: Folks, I suppose by using ARC(since the minimum supported IOS for any app is 4.3), you need not worry about release & auto-release.

Comment: Let's say I do need a deep copy.  How would the code for that be different from the code here?

Comment: @GeneralMike: This should probably be a separate question, but in general (see what I did there?), you want to make sure to copy every object from the original during a deep copy—and make sure that their `-copy` methods also do deep copies.

Comment: @JeffKelley: Yeah that's what I figured, which is why I didn't post another Q.  I was just wondering if there was a better way than a loop-and-copy type thing, but I guess not.  Thx for the help.

Comment: And if the class is immutable, just return object itself without creating a new object.

Comment: @jweyrich you are correct. I added a new answer with this correction.

Comment: I need more explaining here. In both NSObjcet.h and the documentation,  copyWithZone: is always a Class method! +(id) copyWithZone: etc.  That really confused me, because how can a class method copy a specific instance it doesn't know about?  Furthermore the copyWithZone: method definition in NSObject.h - is not available when using ARC!!!! so I can't even implement it.  Please advise/explain

Answer (score 7):

This answer is similar to the accepted, but uses `allocWithZone:` and is updated for ARC. NSZone is foundation class for allocating memory. While ignoring `NSZone` might work for most cases, it is still incorrect.

To correctly implement `NSCopying` you must implement a protocol method which allocates a new copy of the object, with properties that match the values of the original.

In the interface declaration in the header, specify that your class implements the `NSCopying` protocol:

```
@interface Car : NSObject<NSCopying>
{
 ...
}
```

In the .m implementation add a `-(id)copyWithZone` method which looks something like the following:

```
- (id)copyWithZone:(NSZone*)zone
{
    Car* carCopy = [[[self class] allocWithZone:zone] init];

    if (carCopy)
    {
        carCopy.isAvailable = _isAvailable;
        carCopy.transmissionType = _transmissionType;
        ... // assign all other properties.
    }

    return carCopy;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

## **Swift Version**

Just call `object.copy()` to create the copy.

I didn't use `copy()` for value types since those are copied "automatically." But I had to use `copy()` for `class` types.

I ignored the `NSZone` parameter because [docs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nscopying/1410311-copy) say it is deprecated:

> This parameter is ignored. Memory zones are no longer used by
>   Objective-C.

Also, please note that this is a simplified implementation. **If you have subclasses** it gets a bit tricker and you should use dynamic type: `type(of: self).init(transmissionType: transmissionType)`.

```
class Vendor {
    let vendorId: String
    var availableCars: [Car] = []

    init(vendorId: String) {
        self.vendorId = vendorId
    }
}

extension Vendor: NSCopying {
    func copy(with zone: NSZone? = nil) -> Any {
        let copy = Vendor(vendorId: vendorId)
        if let availableCarsCopy = availableCars.map({$0.copy()}) as? [Car] {
            copy.availableCars = availableCarsCopy
        }
        return copy
    }
}

class Car {
    let transmissionType: String
    var isAvailable: Bool = false
    var fees: [Double] = []

    init(transmissionType: String) {
        self.transmissionType = transmissionType
    }
}

extension Car: NSCopying {
    func copy(with zone: NSZone? = nil) -> Any {
        let copy = Car(transmissionType: transmissionType)
        copy.isAvailable = isAvailable
        copy.fees = fees
        return copy
    }
}
```