# Arguments for a copy method versus a copy constructor in Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, copy, clone, copy-constructor

I'm relatively new to the world of Objective-C and have a class that I've written to which I'd like to add the ability to create a copy.

Coming from Java, I know that I could either write a copy constructor or a clone method, with the latter commonly [not being recommended](http://www.javapractices.com/topic/TopicAction.do?Id=71). However, Objective-C is a different language and before I proceed I'd like to understand the arguments for a copy method versus a copy constructor in Objective-C. What is the most commonly used approach?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The recommended way to add the ability to copy objects is by implementing the [NSCopying protocol](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Protocols/NSCopying_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html).
Many foundation classes also implement NSCopying.

Refer to this answer for more information: [Implementing NSCopying](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4089238/implementing-nscopying/4089372#4089372)

Answer (score 1):

Use: `-(id)copyWithZone:(NSZone*)zone` which is part of the `NSCopying protocol`

Example:

in .h:

```
@interface MyClass : NSObject <NSCopying>
```

in .m

```
-(id)copyWithZone:(NSZone*)zone {
    MyClass *copy = [[[self class] allocWithZone: zone] init];
    copy.user = self.user;
    copy.password = self.password;
//    etc

    return copy;
}
```