# NSMutableArray getting changed

Tags: ios

I have an NSMutableArray (detailsMA)having 100 strings like @"True".
Am storing that array in NSMutableDictionary which is already allocated.

```
            NSArray *array1 = [[NSArray alloc] initWithArray:detailsMA];
            [detailsDictionary setObject: array1 forKey:@"detailsMA"];
```

Now i changed the values of detailsMA, like replacing strings to @"False", After that am retrieving the original array values,

```
            [detailsMA removeAllObjects];
            [detailsMA addObjectsFromArray:[detailsDictionary objectForKey:@"detailsMA"]];
```

Here am getting modified values, not the original values.
I need original values.
Please help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should copy the array.

```
NSArray *array1 = [[NSArray alloc] initWithArray:detailsMA copyItems:YES];
```

Don't forget to implement the NSCopying protocol in the classes for the objects to be copied

EDIT:

When you add the objects again, make a copy before adding.

```
[detailsMA addObjectsFromArray:[[NSArray alloc] initWithArray:[detailsDictionary objectForKey:@"detailsMA"] copyItems:YES]];
```

Comment: How to implement NSCopying protocol, can you give me example.

Comment: I thought you were using custom objects. Since you are using NSString, it should be fine anyway.

Comment: Am using custom object, which is having two properties. With out implementing NSCopying it is crashing

Comment: You need to respond to the `-copyWithZone:` selector. Have a look at this answer for a description: http://stackoverflow.com/a/4089372/643109

Comment: Hi Pulkit Goyal, NSArray *array1 = [[NSArray alloc] initWithArray:detailsMA copyItems:YES];
it is working, but after retrieving from dictionary like             [detailsMA removeAllObjects];
[detailsMA addObjectsFromArray:[detailsDictionary objectForKey:@"detailsMA"]];
if change any thing on detailsMA, it is effecting on Dictionary also. I dont want to change Dictionary.

Comment: Don't add objects, make a copy and then add. See updated answer.