# Create copy of a NSMutableArray and edit element only in one array

Tags: iphone, ios, nsmutablearray, nsarray

i have two nsmutablearray:

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSMutableArray *calSeries;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSMutableArray *calSeries2Copy;
```

then i do this:

```
self.calSeries = [self getSeries];
self.calSeries2Copy = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:self.calSeries];
```

the getSeries method fetchObject from the core data, but if i change an element in the calSeries, it change also in the calSeries2Copy, how i can create two array separately so as when i change an element in one array don't change also in the other array?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this,

```
self.calSeries2Copy = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray:self.calSeries copyItems:YES];
```

As per [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSArray_Class/NSArray.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSArray/initWithArray:copyItems:), this should copy if you have implemented `NSCopying` protocol.

> *flag*
>
> If YES, each object in array receives a copyWithZone: message to
> create a copy of the object—objects must conform to the NSCopying
> protocol. In a managed memory environment, this is instead of the
> retain message the object would otherwise receive. The object copy is
> then added to the returned array.
>
> If NO, then in a managed memory environment each object in array
> simply receives a retain message when it is added to the returned
> array.
>
> *Discussion*
>
> After an immutable array has been initialized in this way,
> it cannot be modified.
>
> The copyWithZone: method performs a shallow copy. If you have a
> collection of arbitrary depth, passing YES for the flag parameter will
> perform an immutable copy of the first level below the surface. If you
> pass NO the mutability of the first level is unaffected. In either
> case, the mutability of all deeper levels is unaffected.

Comment: give me this error [Show copyWithZone:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0xc0ad8a0 Show is the element in the array that is fetched from the core data, how i can implement the NSCopying?

Comment: @Piero, Check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4089238/implementing-nscopying. It is already answered here.

Comment: ok thanks i have another question, implementing the NSCopying protocol works only when i call initArray copyItems, in the other cases work normally right?

Comment: It is basically for copying operations. If you want to create a complete copy of an object, this protocol is useful. Check this documentation for more details https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Protocols/NSCopying_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html

Comment: Since the original array contains Core Data objects, it should be noted that `NSManagedObject` does *not* implement the `NSCopying` protocol.

Answer (score 0):

copying an array by default makes a **shallow copy** only. This means that the array is copied but the elements are only retained once more

Copy the items with `[[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray:srcArray copyItems:YES];` to get a **deep copy** where also every element is copied

Comment: Just a note: A *deep copy* is a copy where recursively all elements are copied. This method copies only the first level objects. (Did not downvote though :-)