# Objective C - Qty in an array is always reset to zero, but why?

Tags: objective-c, pointers, reference, nsmutablearray, zero

I am trying to do a program where there is a `product` which I wish to be moved into a `storehouse`.

> Example:
>
> *Move 25 crates of Apples from Inventory (on hand) to a Storehouse.*

When I add the product to the storehouse's `listOfProducts` and then zero the stock, for some reason the storehouse's product is also affected, even though it shouldn't be.

The process should be;

1. Find the product object you want to move into the storehouse
2. Update the storehouse qty, making sure the qty is adding the stock you have on hand
3. Add a product object to the storehouse's listOfProducts
4. Make the inventory stock zero (0)

But its making the storehouse qty 0 too?  Why?  There appears to be no reason why it should be doing this.

It appears to have forced a symlink between the objects I am referencing, even though this is not what is meant to be happening.

Do I need to be making a copy of the object first?

Some notes.

a. Storehouse is an object, each city has a storehouse (ie. city.listOfStorehouses).

b. city.listOfStorehouses is kept in a singleton so saving the state or passing it from page to page is not a problem.

c. **The item gets added to the storehouse, but the qty resets to zero? But why?**

```
// Try to move X goods from inventory -> storehouse
 NSLog(@"Goods to move = %@, %d crates", self.product.name, self.crates);

// I add the qty to the product I want to put into the storehouse        
self.product.qty += self.crates;

// Append the array (I should check if the product already exists but this does not matter right now)
[self.storehouse.listOfProducts addObject:self.product];

// Reset crates because it should always be zero because you've moved them
// from your inventory into a storehouse
self.crates = 0;
```

Okay, so when on the stock page and I move 25 Apples from inventory to the storehouse the reference and qty seem fine.

However, if I refresh/reload the page the qty is reset to zero in the storehouse, even though there is an item there.

I do not know what is causing the storehouse item qty to be set to zero.

Here is a log output;

```
// Log output

// Stock page
// Goods to move = Apples, 25 crates, seems to be storing fine, no problem.
2013-02-16 09:40:27.257 TestApp[1524:c07] Storehouse = (25/500)
2013-02-16 09:40:27.260 TestApp[1524:c07]    #0 storehouse item = Apples with 25 crates

// Previous page
// When I go back to the previous page, the qty is zero?? WHY?
2013-02-16 09:41:33.980 TestApp[1524:c07] Storehouse = (0/500)
2013-02-16 09:41:33.980 TestApp[1524:c07]    #0 storehouse item = Apple with 0 crates
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you assign an object to a variable, it is a *reference* to the original object that is assigned to the variable. This is probably what you refer to as a "symlink".

There is no automatic creation of new objects on variable assignment in Objective-C, but you can declare a property to be a "copy" property, in which case the object will be copied by the property's automatically generated setter method.

You will need to make sure that your object implements the [`NSCopying` protocol](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Protocols/NSCopying_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html). How to implement that protocol for a custom object is also discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4089238/implementing-nscopying).

Comment: I'll have a go of doing copying, I've not done it before; I don't want to be copying (by writing out in code) every attribute because there is quite a lot of them.

Comment: I think you are right, I did a basic test using nscopy and I was able to ensure the quantity was at least working, although I only tested a bit of it as I am very new to nscopy.