# Two objects that points to one

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have a methode like this :

```
-(void)myMethod:(MyClass *)object {

self.object1 = object;
self.object2 = object;

....
}
```

and `object1` and `object2` are declared like this :

```
property (nonatomic, strong) MyClass *object1;
property (nonatomic, strong) MyClass *object2;
```

and MyClass is like this :

```
@interface MyClass :NSObject

....
@end
```

and later when I modify the `self.object1` the `self.object2` is modified to, I would like that `self.object2` don't change its value when modifing `self.object1`

Comment: Then don't assign the same value to both!!  PLEASE, PLEASE spend some time learning about pointers and objects before you try to use Objective-C.

Comment: i would like to save the old value, i thing you have not understand my problem, PLEASE, PLEASE, Understand question before answering.

Comment: If you understood objects and pointers you'd never have needed to ask this question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to make the two properties `copy` instead of `sttrong`. But then you need to make your `MyClass` conform to the `NSCopying` protocol and you must implement the `copyWithZone:` method.

Comment: Correct. Relevant answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4089238/implementing-nscopying

Comment: Can someone please explain the down vote? No one learns anything if there is no explanation.

Answer (score 3):

You don't have two objects that point to one.

You have two pointers that point to the same object.

So if you modify `self.object1` by definition it will modify the `self.object2`

The only way to change this behavior is to have object1 and object2 point to two different objects.