# Deep copy of an NSMutableArray of custom objects with NSMutableArray members

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsmutablearray, deep-copy

I'm trying to make a deep copy of an `NSMutableArray` whose objects are instances of a custom class similar to this:

```
@interface CustomParent : NSObject
@property NSInteger Id;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSString *IdStr;
@property (weak, nonatomic) NSDate *Date; 
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSMutableArray *CustomChildren;
@property (strong, nonatomic) CustomType *Type;
@property float Value;
@end
```

I know there are lots of posts dealing with copying objects, but I don´t find examples for getting a complete copy of objects with collection members or properties. `NSMutableArray *dstArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray:srcArray copyItems:YES];` raises an exception involving the `copyWithZone` method.

How can I do this? Thanks!

Comment: take a look at the NSCoding protocol : https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/Protocols/NSCoding_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html

Comment: you probably mean `NSCopying`

Comment: @AppsDev, any luck with the proposed solution?

Comment: @GabrielePetronella I read the post you referred and it seems to work, thanks!

Comment: @LescaiIonel I tried `NSCoding` before and it takes a lot of time for copying many objects connected to a class. Thins `NSCopying` should be faster.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

In order to deep copy the content of the array

```
[[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray:srcArray copyItems:YES];
```

will send `copyWithZone:` to every object inside the collection. If they don't respond to this selector, you'll get a crash.

Have your `CustomParent` class to conform to the [`NSCopying`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Protocols/NSCopying_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html) protocol and you're done.

Here's some extra info on how do achieve it: [Implementing NSCopying](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4089238/implementing-nscopying)