# Crashing On CopyWithZone: Method

Tags: ios, nscopying

I have created one class which is subclass of NSObject(nsme as GroupClass).In that class I have created one property which is belonging from 'id' ,like

```
@property(nonatomic,retain)id myObj;
```

Now I am standing on way where I have one mutable array,that array contains instances of my GroupClass.so I am getting one copy in similar way

```
GroupClass* objG=[array objectAtIndex:i];
```

now I want one another copy of objG.I searched .And I found NSCopying Protocol.So I added as delegate NSCopying to GroupClass and also added copyWithZone method.Here it is

```
-(id)copyWithZone:(NSZone *)zone
{
  GroupClass *copy = [[[self class] allocWithZone: zone] init];
  copy.myObj=[myObj copyWithZone: zone];
  return copy;
}
```

Here I need deep copy.but it is always crashing after allocation line.Please help me.Thanking You.

Comment: myObj's class type is unknown so how can [myObj copyWithZone...] work? maybe myObj did not even implement copyWithZone method. You need to know what its type is, cast it to that type, and call its copyWithZone method if it exists. If id myObj is type of GroupClass, then it would cause an unending recursive call and crash

Comment: then how can it work if I wrote [copy setmyObj:[self myObj]]; ?If I am using this line then it will allow to copy but that copy will shallow copy.And I need Deep copy.

Comment: No, it wont, it will only be a reference (shallow copy). What is the type of myObj?

Comment: thats what I am saying if it is crashing because of 'id' type then it should not work with [copy setmyObj:[self myObj]]; also...

Comment: That statement will not give error but it wont "copy" it.

Comment: What is its real type? Did you mean to pass more than one type of class there?

Comment: it is...it gives me shallow copy.Ok so what is solution now?

Comment: You need to implement copyWithZone: method in all types of classes that you are storing in myObj.

Comment: we have used ID because sometimes we get arrays,sometimes dictionaries and sometimes classes.that why we used ID

Comment: can you give me link of this kind of tutorial?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4089238/implementing-nscopying  Regarding arrays for example, array will not deep copy its items, it will issue copywithzone message to its objects. If they implement it, then they will be deep copied. You may need to rethink about your design of this class.

Comment: yes I think I need to restructure it..thanks a lot...

Answer (score 0):

Not all `NSObject` subclasses adopt the `NSCopying` protocol. The problem sounds like you are sending this message to an object which doesn't recognise it.

It doesn't matter that your `GroupClass` adopts `NSCopying`, that is not the problem. You are calling copyWithZone: on myObj, whatever that is.

This line of code:

```
copy.myObj=[myObj copyWithZone: zone];
```

Is almost certainly what is causing the crash.

**EDIT**

Not knowing what myObj is, I would recommend that if it is possible, and isn't a bad idea, that you subclass whatever the class is.

If it is a UIView for example, I would subclass it like so:

```
@class JVView : UIView <NSCopying>
```

I would then implement the `copyWithZone:` method appropriately, copying any of the properties of the instance that you feel are necessary.

Comment: so what should i do? should i create subclass for myObj?