# Creating a copy of an NSMutableArray with custom objects

Tags: objective-c, cocos2d-iphone

I've been searching around for the solution to this for quite a while, and none of the other threads have helped. Basically, what I want to accomplish is creating an array of custom objects as a singleton, load them into my level, then create a copy of them since variables assigned to these objects will be manipulated. When the level is complete (or failed) though, I want these objects to remain the same so I can reload them.

Below are some things I've tried.

```
- (void)spawnStartTiles {
    //where _puzzleGridTilesArray and curLevel.gridTiles are NSMutableArrays
    [_puzzleGridTilesArray removeAllObjects];
    _puzzleGridTilesArray = [curLevel.gridTiles mutableCopy];
    CCLOG(@"tile in curlevel %@", curLevel.gridTiles[0]); //want these to log DIFFERENT objects
    CCLOG(@"tile in puzzle array %@", _puzzleGridTilesArray[0]);//want these to log DIFFERENT objects
}
```

The above logs the same object ID.

```
- (void)spawnStartTiles {
    //where _puzzleGridTilesArray and curLevel.gridTiles are NSMutableArrays
    _puzzleGridTilesArray = [self cloneArray:curLevel.gridTiles];
    CCLOG(@"tile in curlevel %@", curLevel.gridTiles[0]); //want these to log DIFFERENT objects
    CCLOG(@"tile in puzzle array %@", _puzzleGridTilesArray[0]);//want these to log DIFFERENT objects
}

-(NSMutableArray*)cloneArray:(NSMutableArray *)myArray {
    return [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray: myArray];
}
```

Still logs same object ID.

```
- (void)spawnStartTiles {
    //where _puzzleGridTilesArray and curLevel.gridTiles are NSMutableArrays
    _puzzleGridTilesArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray:curLevel.gridTiles copyItems:YES];
    CCLOG(@"tile in curlevel %@", curLevel.gridTiles[0]); //want these to log DIFFERENT objects
    CCLOG(@"tile in puzzle array %@", _puzzleGridTilesArray[0]);//want these to log DIFFERENT objects
}
```

The above gives a runtime error. I think this is because the objects I am copying are a custom class named `Tile`. The class is a CCNode, and the .h file is below.

```
#import "CCNode.h"

@interface Tile : CCNode

@property (nonatomic, assign) NSInteger value;
@property (nonatomic, assign) NSInteger gemLevel;
@property (nonatomic, assign) BOOL mergedThisRound;
- (void)updateValueDisplay:(BOOL)bannerTiles difficultyMode:(int)difficultyMode;
- (void)updateOpacity:(NSInteger)opacityVariable;
- (void)tileHasBeenSelected:(BOOL)tileHasBeenTouched;

@end
```

Is there a way to somehow transform this class so that is can be copied? I've looked at http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/Copying_Objects_in_Objective-C and [Implementing NSCopying](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4089238/implementing-nscopying) and I'm still confused, so further help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You get an error because `[[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray:curLevel.gridTiles copyItems:YES]` calls `copyWithZone:` on each item in the array. Your items must conform to `NSCopying` for you to use this method, but this is the correct approach.

To implement NSCopying:

1. Update your `Tile` class to add the protocol, i.e. `@interface Tile : CCNode <NSCopying>`
2. Implement the method `- (id)copyWithZone:(NSZone *)zone` in your Tile implementation.
3. In that method, allocate a new instance of `Tile` and assign all of it's properties to that of your current instance.

Comment: Thanks! This worked for me =) now I understand it a lot better too